# ngIf and ngSwitch won't replace divs in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to open a modal and while my GET request to the API is running, I want the modal to show a loading wheel. Once the request completes, I update a "show" variable and the modal content gets replaced with a form with pre-populated values from the API. As well as this, I have a conditional "error" section that adds a div for errors to the top of the form if the API returns any errors. I'm using Angular Elements to get the modal's HTML/functionality, and the elements are being used inside an ASP.NET MVC solution. This all works fine in every browser except for IE11. The html is shown below:

```
<form id="addFormSolo" #f1="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="post(f1);" ngNativeValidate>
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="show">
<div *ngSwitchCase="false">
  <div class="modal-body" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <div class="loader" style="justify-content: center;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngSwitchCase="true">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div [ngSwitch]="hasErrors">
      <div *ngSwitchCase="true" class="alert alert-warning modalView validation-summary-errors" role="alert" data-valmsg-summary="true">
        <h5>Please correct the following errors</h5>
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let error of errors">{{error}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="editpage popup form-horizontal container-fluid">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label required" for="description" style="text-align: right; padding-top: 7px;"> Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameAddSolo" name="description" maxlength="70" [ngModel]="model.description">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="editpage popup form-horizontal container-fluid">
      <div class="form-group row" style="align-items:center;">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label required" for="code" style="text-align: right; padding-top: 7px;"> Code:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 editPageValue">
          <input type="text" class="form-control codeInput" id="codeAddSolo" name="code" maxlength="20" [ngModel]="model.code">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="checkbox" style="padding-top:0px;">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" class="activeInput" id="activeAddSolo" name="active" [ngModel]="model.isActive">
              <span class="text">
                Active
              </span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save & Close" style="margin-right: 5px">
    </div>
    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**There is indeed a closing form and ng-container tag but I'm having trouble with formatting**

I've tried using polyfills, tried setting target = ES5 but this gives me "TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function." when I try chrome/other browsers, and still doesn't make the ngIf/ngSwitch stuff work. I've even tried using babel to transpile. Is there something I'm missing, or does this conditional rendering just not work with IE11 no matter what?

Comment: In IE browser, is there any error message? Try to use F12 developer tools to check it. According to your code, the posted HTML resource doesn't contain the end tags (the </ng-container> and </form> tag), please try to add it. Besides, based on [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24556), you could try to change the "target":"es5" in the tsconfig.json to "target":"es2015". If still not working, can you create a [stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @ZhiLv-MSFT , there's no error message in the developer tools at all. I do have the closing tags, but as I mentioned in bold in the post, I'm having trouble with formatting the post, so I had to leave them out to be able to post the question.
One thing I forgot to mention is that I'm using angular elements, (which I'll add to the post), so I occassionally get an error from IE that says "Cannot execute code from a freed script". The elements are being created  in an ASP.NET application.

Comment: I have tried to test your code but can't reproduce the problem. Can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). it might be easier for us to reproduce the problem the solve the problem.